# replace React.js class with rerendered class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.js to build a web app that displays a table with a bunch of protocols that it receives using a REST api. Id like to replace ONLY the table.

inside the body of the `index.html` page i have this:

```
<div id= "content"><>/div>
```

when my jsx script renders the app it takes over the content div.

Is it possible to do the same thing but replace one of the  react classes using the id?

```
var tableChange = function(url) {
 React.render(
  <myTable source={url}/>, document.getElementById("myOldTable")
);
}
```

where the original react app contains this:

```
<myTable id="myOldTable" source={this.props.url} />
```

When I run the code the following way it says that its a null element and it cant be found.

Comment: The code that renders the original table should just rerender it.

Comment: @FelixKling the code does rerender it, but i can only call a rerender from outside the original table or its children. The element that is calling it is neither.

Comment: You have to render into the parent of the table. Basically the same as the original render call. If the table is only part of a larger component that is rendered then you are out of luck. You can't replace some part of a larger React component from outside.

Comment: let me make sure I'm understanding you. so in order to re-render the table i must re-render the whole App and pass in the new url that  way?

Comment: Yes, that's how React works. It doesn't have to be the whole app. Just the component that renders the table.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html